# Enable multicast between server/client application

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, opensuse, multicast

I have a VirtualBox VM running openSuse and an application that is meant to multicast data. I also have an application that is on the same machine running on Windows 7 that is meant to receive the multicast.

The receiver is not receiving the data and I am not sure where the problem is. I know the receiver and sender applications both work as they have been tested elsewhere.

This is what I have done so far:

```
sudo /sbin/route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth3
```

The server application is using the following multicast address and port: `224.0.0.25/6787`

Is there something I need to do on the Windows 7 machine to enable multicast to be received? Or is there a problem with the addresses I am using? Or that I am running in a WM? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What type of network connections does the VM have?

Comment: I tried a few options: `NAT` (which allowed internet connection), and `Bridged Adapter` (which did not). There are a few other choices, like `NAT Network` and `Internal Network` that I have not tried yet.

Comment: Multicast traffic will not traverse a NAT adapter, so if you need internet access on the machine you'll probably need to add a second network adapter and use a "Host Only" adapter type.

Comment: That was it. Thank you. The problem with setting up something so complicated, when it goes wrong there are so many things to point fingers at.